# How to make unique drupal theme for one page

Tags: drupal, themes

I have a custom drupal theme which i would need to customiza a bit. I have ten pages that would need unique layout, different than on normal pages. Now i know i can make a new page_something.tpl and to the name the name of the page to make an own template for one page but how can i make all 10 pages to use that template?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a content type for the pages you wish to look the same as often they will share similiar features in terms of content (CCK fields).

For theming you can the use ([from d.o](http://drupal.org/node/190815#node-suggestion)):

---

```
node-[type].tpl.php
base template: node.tpl.php
```

In Drupal 7, templates for specific content types are created slightly different than in Drupal 6.

Drupal 6: node-mytype.tpl.php
Drupal 7: node--mytype.tpl.php

See [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php) in the Drupal API documentation for more information.

Note that in order to override the template for a specific node type, the theme must also implement the base node.tpl.php file. If this file is omitted, the theme will not detect the presence of node-[type].tpl.php files.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the ThemeKey module](http://drupal.org/project/themekey). With it a different theme shows based on conditions you set.

Comment: but it will require two different themes to be created/customised then using themekey templates can be applied , but if using only one theme this will not work